# PhpStorm не знает переменную currentScript — «Unresolved variable currentScript». Как сделать так, чтобы он знал ее и не выдавал Warning'ов?

Tags: javascript, phpstorm

PhpStorm не знает переменную currentScript — «Unresolved variable currentScript». Как сделать так, чтобы он знал ее и не выдавал Warning'ов? Вот скриншот:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

попробуйте обновиться до последней версии - там это должно работать (если, конечно, подключена библиотека **HTML** в **Settings | Languages & Frameworks | JavaScript | Libraries**):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Что значит "обновиться до последней версии"? PhpStorm обновить? У меня 2017.2 версия.
Библиотека HTML подключена. https://ibb.co/dcPQRb

Comment: да, PHPStorm. Начиная с версии 2017.3, он использует стандартные typescript библиотеки для web api, что решает большую часть проблем с подсветкой стандартных функций